# Cryptic error message when deploying LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

When deploying my LWC (with `sfdx force:source:deploy`) I get this error message. Unfortunately I cannot provide the source code, which is quite lengthy. Any idea about how to go about tracking down this error?

```
Deploying pulseListView...
Job ID | 0Af3i00000Pgl2qCAB
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 1/2 Components
TYPE   PROJECT PATH                                          PROBLEM
─────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  velo/main/default/lwc/pulseListView/pulseListView.js  bad result: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `messages` of 'undefined' or 'null'.    at JavascriptLintingService.lint (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.7.10-228.5/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/dist/linting/index.js:43:48)    at lint (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.7.10-228.5/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/dist/compile.js:276:62)    at compile (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.7.10-228.5/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/dist/compile.js:37:27)    at Object.oboe.on ([eval]:1:200)    at /home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.7.10-228.5/node_modules/oboe/dist/oboe-node.js:2038:25    at apply (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.7.10-228.5/node_modules/oboe/dist/oboe-node.js:224:13)    at /home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.7.10-228.5/node_modules/oboe/dist/oboe-node.j
```

For what it's worth, the problem appears when deploying component A if and only if component A imports component B, while component B deploys just fine on its own.

Comment: The error message clearly indicates `Cannot destructure property 'messages'`. Have you looked into which component has this `messages` property and tried to troubleshoot?

Comment: To get help from the community you're going to need to include code snippets, not just error messages. It looks like you have an issue in the "pulseListView" component. As arut said, have a look see where you reference a "messages" property in that component (this could be in the JavaScript or the template). As it stands there isn't enough information to let the community assist further.

Comment: This error message is not from my code. It is apparently from code running on the Salesforce server (see the paths). I have no messages property in my code that anybody would be trying to destructure. It seems highly probably that this is a bug in the LWC compiler. My question is how best to proceed in such cases to tracking down the problem.

Note also that, as I mentioned, no error is reported when I deploy just the dependent component (which also does not have any `messages`). The error is reported when I deploy `pulseListView`, which `import`s the dependent component.

Comment: In any case, if this was my code, which as I said it is not, there is no reason that it would be executing and thus raising this error at deploy time.